# Difference between Stable, unstable sets , manifolds and subspaces?

Tags: terminology, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

I am confused about the difference between the stable sets, unstable sets ; stable and unstable manifolds; and stable and unstable subspaces of a fixed point $p$ of a map $f : M \rightarrow M$ where $M$ is a boundaryless manifold.

Looking at the Wikipedia article, I see the terminology for the words sets and manifolds are used identically [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_manifold_theorem).

Comment: Probably what's happening is that if $f$ is "nice" (say, suffuciently differentiable) then the sets are manifolds, and if $f$ is really nice (that is, linear) then the manifods are subspaces.